# How should I pick the right Docker image?

Tags: docker

Docker images are often available with different base OS images. 
I am not going to install other applications in that container. I will have separate container for each application I need.

Does it matter which base image I choose? If not why would I choose a larger image instead of a smaller one? What would I be giving away?

For example, Kong image is available in two variants with very different sizes:

CentOS based - 143.23 MB

Alpine based - 42.71 MB

https://hub.docker.com/_/kong?tab=tags

BTW, I am going to run the docker on Ubuntu.

Comment: It totally depends on your requirements and usage. Moreover one should chose image with smaller size, so it could reduce size and other overheads also.

Comment: My requirement is just that the container should run  the contained application. I am not going to install other applications in that container. I will have separate container for each application I need.

Comment: Depending on our end goal, if alpine based image is able to successfully contains your application, then it must be a good option. because it is light-weight with least no of packages and other dependencies.

Comment: I am new to docker, as I understand, the best practice is to have separate containers for each application and not to modify standard images of pulled form docker hub. So I won't be installing anything of my own inside these containers. So I suppose everything should run just fine even in the alpine based images. Is that correct?

Comment: Your application can run on any base image, the question is which is more suitable then other, alpine base image is just size of `5mb` and you can alpine with 10MB RAM , but you can not run the centos

Comment: But then why would one ever choose the CentOS image? Obviously there is some trade off. What is it?

Comment: What if you want to run Wowza a streaming engine? that is only available in centos? so the only way is centos. Every one moving to alpine and a expericed persion will very less go for other images. jenkins move to alpine, ejabberd, mariadb and many more....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only going to run the image as-is, as I assume from

> I am not going to install other applications in that container. I will have separate container for each application I need.

then it doesn't matter (unless the image's developer notes it does, of course!).

If you're going to use one of those images as a base image, then it does matter some – as noted here in comments and answers, the different distributions these images are based on have different tools and capabilities (Ubuntu/Debian has `apt` for a package manager, Alpine uses musl libc and has `apk`).

At that point, you'll want to choose a base image that has the tooling you're comfortable with and supports the changes you'll be enacting on top of the base image.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comment it totally depends upon your need, but in the mentioned two images I will go for alpine.

> Does it matter which base image I choose?

Yes its matter, there are a different reason to choose smaller one, some advantage may be

- Smaller in size (build, pull, push is fast)
- Take little space as the compared large image
- Consume less MEMORY by the OS itself as compared to CentOS
- Alpine is considered secure and fast
- Alpine is an offical image for [docker registry](https://github.com/docker/distribution-library-image/blob/0b6ea3ba50b65563600a717f07db4cfa6f18f957/amd64/Dockerfile)

You can read the experimental base article [here](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/the-3-biggest-wins-when-using-alpine-as-a-base-docker-image).

**SMALL**

> Alpine Linux is built around musl libc and busybox. This makes it
>   smaller and more resource efficient than traditional GNU/Linux
>   distributions. A container requires no more than **8 MB** and a
>   minimal installation to disk requires around **130 MB of storage**.
>   Not only do you get a **fully-fledged Linux environment** but a large
>   selection of packages from the repository.
>
> Binary packages are thinned out and split, giving you even more
>   control over what you install, which in turn keeps your environment as
>   small and efficient as possible.

[alpinelinux](https://alpinelinux.org/about/)

Comment: I totally understand the advantages of a smaller image, I wanted to understand what I lose by not choosing the larger image.

Comment: You are not losing any thing, the other OS designed for VM, container, Machine or any platform but that is the alpine that is designed for containrization not anything else

Comment: @Dojo the downside could be that you will need to install more packages manually while using Alpine image. But this means you won't have unnecessary apps inside your docker container, since number of pre-installed is limited.

Comment: Also, not all software is compatible with Alpine's musl libc.

Comment: @AKX yes but in the above case the Alpine suit and the offical image exist so I think better to go for alpine?

Comment: Just a quick warning. If you are going to be deploying your containers in Kubernetes, you need to be aware of the Alpine ndots DNS issue.